# Remove search icon from ui-filterable?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

My form looks like this:

[image: search form]

Code looks like this:

```
<form class="ui-filterable" id="ex-search">
    <input id="rich-autocomplete-input" data-type="search" placeholder="Search Exercise" />
</form>
```

How do I remove the search icon? I have tried a few different options such as changing the background image, editing the margin etc. but couldn't manage to remove it.

Comment: Try `.ui-filterable:before{content:"" !important}` in css

Comment: Where's your CSS? We need to see that if you want us to help.

Comment: `.ui-filterable:before{content:"" !important}` didn't work :( I haven't made any changes to the CSS, it's using the default style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.ui-input-search:after {
  content: none !important;
}

.ui-input-search input {
  padding-left: 0.75em !important;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! Do you have any idea how to remove the "X" that pops up to the right when you type something in the box? It's not a big issue but would look good without it.

Comment: @user3049858 Check out this site that came up when I searched your request on Google: http://geektnt.com/how-to-remove-x-from-search-input-field-on-chrome-and-ie.html